# Are QuickFind and QuickUnion two ways of approaching the same problem?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to understand the differences between these 2 algorithms. QuickUnion seems to operate on an entirely different kind of data structure than QuickFind, yet they seem to be used for the exact same problems. Can someone help clarify?

I'm doing Algorithms 1 on Coursera

Comment: [Disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Comment: The lectures on coursera explain very well the differences between the two, what the pros and cons of each are, and introduce `UnionFind` as a combination of all the pros. You can use this resource too: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/